# Can't call method "print" on an undefined value

Tags: perl

**Can't call method print on an undefined value in line 40  line 2.**

Here is the code. I use FileHandle to settle files:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use FileHandle;

die unless (@ARGV ==4|| @ARGV ==5);

my @input =();
$input[0]=$ARGV[3];
$input[1]=$ARGV[4] if ($#ARGV==4);
chomp @input;
$input[0] =~ /([^\/]+)$/;
my $out = "$1.insert";
my $lane= "$1";

my %fh=();
open (Info,">$ARGV[1]")  || die "$!";
open (AA,"<$ARGV[0]")   || die "$!";

while(<AA>){
    chomp;
    my @inf=split;
    my $iden=$inf[0];
    my $outputfile="$ARGV[2]/$iden";
    $fh{$iden}=FileHandle->new(">$outputfile");
}
close AA;

foreach my $input (@input) {
    open (IN, "<$input" ) or die "$!" ;
    my @path=split (/\//,$input);
    print Info "#$path[-1]\n";
    while (<IN>) {
        my $line1 = $_;
        my ($id1,$iden1) = (split "\t", $line1)[6,7];
        my $line2 = <IN> ;
        my ($id2,$iden2) = (split "\t", $line2)[6,7];
        if ($id1 eq '+' && $id2 eq '-') {
            my @inf=split(/\t/,$line1);
            $fh{$iden1}->print($line1);
            $fh{$iden2}->print($line2);
        }
    }
    close IN;
}
```

I’ve tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `$iden1` is invalid for a certain input line, therefor `$fh{$iden1}` results in an invalid file handle, therefor `->print` cannot be called on it.

Comment: You could check for `definedness` and create a new filehandle before trying to print.  `$fh{$iden1} ||= Filehandle->new(">$ARGV[2]/$iden1");  $fh{$iden1}->print(...);`

Comment: @Jack: Perhaps more importantly than the way it looks, adding line numbers makes it very awkward to copy and paste your code so that we can try it ourselves. If you need to refer to a specific line in your code then it's best to add a comment that highlights the line. You could even get fancy and use Perl's preprocessor that acts on comments, so that `#line 42` followed by `die` on the next line will display `Died at <source file name> line 42` at run time. The hash `#` must be the first character on the line.

Comment: Drop `FileHandle` and use `open $fh{$iden}, '>', $outputfile or die $!`

Answer (score 2):

Please remember that the primary worth of a Stack Overflow post is not to fix your particular problem, but to help the thousands of others who may be stuck in the same way. With that in mind, *"I fixed it, thanks, bye"* is more than a little selfish

As I said in my comment, using `open` directly on a hash element is much preferable to involving `FileHandle`. Perl will *autovivify* the hash element and create a file handle for you, and most people at all familiar with Perl will thank you for not making them read up again on the `FileHandle` documentation

I rewrote your code like this, which is much more Perlish and relies less on "magic numbers" to access `@ARGV`. You should really assign `@ARGV` to a list of named scalars, or - better still - use [`Getopt::Long`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long) so that they are named anyway

You should `open` your file handles as *late* as possible, and `close` the ***output*** handles *early*. This is effected most easily by using *lexical file handles* and limiting their scope to a block. Perl will implicitly close lexical handles for you when they go out of scope

There is no need to `chomp` the contents of `@ARGV`unless you could be be called under strange and errant circumstances, in which case you need to do a *hell* of a lot more to verify the input

You never use the result of `$input[0] =~ /([^\/]+)$/` or the variables `$out` and `$lane`, so I removed them

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

# $ARGV[0] -- input file
# $ARGV[1] -- output log file
# $ARGV[2] -- directory for outputs per ident
# $ARGV[3] -- 1, $input[0]
# $ARGV[4] -- 2, $input[1] or undef

die "Fix the parameters" unless @ARGV == 4 or @ARGV == 5;

my @input = @ARGV[3,4];

my %fh;

{
    open my $fh, '<', $ARGV[0] or die $!;

    while ( <$fh> ) {
        my $id         = ( split )[0];
        my $outputfile = "$ARGV[2]/$id";
        open $fh{$id}, '>', $outputfile or die qq{Unable to open "$outputfile" for output: $!};
    }
}

open my $log_fh, '>', $ARGV[1] or die qq{Unable to open "$ARGV[1]" for output: $!};

for my $input ( @input ) {

    next unless $input; # skip unspecified parameters

    my @path = split qr|/|, $input;   # Really should be done by File::Spec
    print $log_fh "#$path[-1]\n";     # Or File::Basename

    open my $fh, '<', $input or die qq{Unable to open "$input" for input: $!};

    while ( my $line0 = <$fh> ) {

        chomp $line0;

        my $line1 = <$fh>;
        chomp $line1;

        my ($id0, $iden0) = (split /\t/, $line0)[6,7];
        my ($id1, $iden1) = (split /\t/, $line1)[6,7];

        if ( $id0 eq '+' and $id1 eq '-' ) {

            $fh{$_} or die qq{No output file for "$_"} for $iden0, $iden1;

            print { $fh{$iden0} } $line0;
            print { $fh{$iden1} } $line1;
        }
    }
}

while ( my ($iden, $fh) = each %fh ) {
    close $fh or die qq{Unable to close file handle for "$iden": $!};
}
```

Comment: I think you have an error in the final `print`s. You want to print `$line0` to `$fh{$iden0}` and `$line1` to `$fh{$iden1}`. You're printing `$line0` to both filehandles.

Comment: You're saying it's important to `close` the filehandles as soon as possible, but you let them go out of scope, which implicitly closes them. While that's valid and I'd do the same, I believe in the context of your answer an explanation would be useful.

Comment: I checked the inputfile (`$ARGV[3]`) acorrding to the Dave Cross advice. There are some format errors about inputfile (`$ARGV[3]`).  It is not the code error. The `keys` of `%fh` is not match the `$id`s. Although outputfiles are generated, they are all empty files.

Comment: @DaveCross: Thank you very much. Now that I'm back at a PC I've been able to fix what I think was a valiant attempt at writing Perl code on my tablet! Even `print $fh{$iden0} $line0` is a syntax error, which needs to be `print { $fh{$iden0} } $line0`. There was also a missing semicolon in `next unless $input;`. I appreciate your scrutiny.

Comment: @simbabque: I wrote that ***output*** handles should be closed early. There is very little chance or impact if an input handle fails to close successfully, and they may be left languishing if it makes the code more accessible. The only output handles here are the ones in `%fh`, which I close explicitly in a loop at the end of the code. I've added a proper test for success as well, which should have been there in the first place. I appreciate your comment: it's always nice to feel that my mistakes will be caught.

Comment: At least on a tablet you have an almost proper keyboard. I start struggling when I comment from my phone in the bus and have to put inline code with backticks.

Comment: @simbabque: Try [**Hacker's Keyboard**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard&hl=en_GB) if you're running Android. You get backticks as well as cursor keys, Ctrl, Alt, and Esc.

Comment: @Borodin I'll try that, thanks. Usually I use Switfkey. But it says _are you missing the key layout you're used from your computer?_ – I would never be able to write on my phone with [this thing](http://i.imgur.com/LX3s5dS.jpg)! :D

Comment: @simbabque: Haha. That looks very edible! Swiftkey is excellent for writing English, but gets in the way if you're using symbols and precise spacing.

Comment: @Borodin not sure I would want to eat [PBT keycaps](https://deskthority.net/wiki/Keycap_construction#PBT), but the brown Cherry MX switche underneath might be nicely crunchy. :) I'll try the Hacker's Keyboard next time I have to write something from the phone. Already installed it.

Answer (score 1):

**You don't have any error handling on this line:**

```
$fh{$iden}=FileHandle->new(">$outputfile");
```

It's possible that opening a filehandle is silently failing, and only producing an error when you try to print to it. For example, if you have specified an invalid filename.

Also, **you never check if `$iden1` and `$iden2` are names of open filehandles that actually exist.**  It's possible one of them does not exist.

In particular, you aren't removing a newline from `$line1`, so if `$iden1` and `$iden2` happen to be the last values on the line, this will be included in the name you are trying to use, and it will fail.

Comment: I checked. The outputfiles had been generated.

Comment: However, the outputfiles are all empty.

Answer (score 1):

In your first `while` loop, you set up a hash of filehandles that you will write to later. The keys in this hash are the "iden" strings from the first file passed to the program.

Later, you parse another file and use the "iden" values in that file to choose which filehandle to write data to. But one (or more) of the "iden" values in the second file is missing from the first file. So that filehandle can't be found in the `%fh` hash. Because you don't check for that, you get `undef back from the hash and you can't print to an undefined filehandle.

To fix it, put a check before trying to use one of the filehandles from the `%fh` hash.

```
die "Unknown fh identifier '$iden1'" unless exists $fh{$iden1};
die "Unknown fh identifier '$iden2'" unless exists $fh{$iden2};
$fh{$iden1}->print($line1);
$fh{$iden2}->print($line2);
```

Comment: I found the problem after I used the way you suggested. Thanks!